# What are the differences between microkernel and microservices architectures

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, microkernel

I'm trying to implement it so i was trying to gather as much information as possible to help me with the implementation. but i just made me more confused.

I have read Software Architecture Patterns by Mark Richards.
I have noticed that in the book there are two types of software architectures:

1. [Microkernel Architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch03.html).
2. [Microservices Architecture Pattern](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch04.html).

So what is the difference between the two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what perspectives are you looking for comparison?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microkernel typically refers to a architecture where there is a central core (the kernel), with plugins around it.  for example if you have used an IDE, there is a core text editor (which in this case is the kernel), but you can add loads of plugins such as git, unit testing or extra languages.

Microservices is a pattern where multiple, individual modules do their own thing but work together.  For example I might create a module to handle Customers and a totally separate module to handle Orders. They might communicate between each other  but there is no central component.  Customers and Orders are equally in charge of their own features.

In the Microkernel architecture, the kernel is at the center of everything and plugins add to functionality to the kernel.  In microservices architectures each microservice stands alone as its own concept and they communicate with each other in a mesh.

This has no bearing on how they are implemented. You could do both patterns as a single program or as plugins or as separate web-apps.  What sets them apart is the idea of a central kernel in the microkernel architecture vs the decentralized mesh or cooperating modules in microservices.

Comment: Good answer except for the last paragraph. Microservices cannot be a single program; each microservice is a separate component that is independently deployed. Microservices are not plugins that adhere to a pluggable interface; each microservice defines its own contract and there can be multiple clients, not a single kernel/engine.

Comment: I disagree. micro services are "is a separate component", sure.  " independently deployed" often, but id argue not required.  " Microservices are not plugins" agreed. IMO You can still build a set of micro-services with hard coded connections into a single application.  The important part is the discreet modules with their own contracts. these could be in memory contracts as interfaces in something like C# or Java and still meet that requirement